# Use `@annotation.varargs` on constructors

Tags: scala

I want to declare a class like this:

```
class StringSetCreate(val s: String*) {
 // ...
}
```

and call that in Java. The problem is that the constructor is of type

```
public StringSetCreate(scala.collection.Seq)
```

So in java, you need to fiddle around with the scala sequences which is ugly.

I know that there is the `@annotation.varargs` annotation which, if used on a method, generates a second method which takes the java varargs.

This annotation does not work on constructors, at least I don't know where to put it. I found a [Scala Issue SI-8383](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8383) which reports this problem. As far as I understand there is no solution currently. Is this right? Are there any workarounds? Can I somehow define that second constructor by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is already filed as https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8383 .

For a workaround I'd recommend using a factory method (perhaps on the companion object), where `@varargs` should work:

```
object StringSetCreate {
  @varargs def build(s: String*) = new StringSetCreate(s: _*)
}
```

Then in Java you call `StringSetCreate.build("a", "b")` rather than using `new`.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it provides a workaround.